# C# parse bitcoin blockchain to get balance of an address

Tags: blockchain, c#, nbitcoin

Is there a way to scan the Bitcoin blockchain in C# without using an external API? I am looking for the amount of spendable money of a Bitcoin address.

I am using NBitcoin.

```
// create new key pair based on private key
NBitcoin.Key key = new NBitcoin.Key(privateKey, privateKey.Length, false);

// parse blk*.dat
// get balance for address key.PubKey.Hash
// How to do that?
```

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible to do. The blockchain contains all the information needed.

Comment: @GregHewgill how he will query blockchain with NBitcoin?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about how to use NBitcoin specifically. However, I've done exactly this with Python (for the blockchain of a different coin, but the structure is largely the same), so it's certainly possible.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784519/NBitcoin-How-to-scan-the-Blockchain

Answer (score 4):

How about running a [QBitNinja](https://github.com/MetacoSA/QBitNinja) server locally?

```
var client = new QBitNinjaClient(baseAddress:"specify host here, you probably want localhost", Network.TestNet);
var balanceModel = client.GetBalance(dest: [Add any IDestination here, like new BitcoinAddress("mivD5GHroixrzgjv6Ww73pV5R55PcL8JdM", Network.TestNet)], unspentOnly: true).Result;
if (balanceModel.Operations.Count == 0) 
    throw new Exception("No coins to spend");
var unspentCoins = new List<Coin>();
foreach (var operation in balanceModel.Operations)
            unspentCoins.AddRange(operation.ReceivedCoins.Select(coin => coin as Coin)); 
var balance = unspentCoins.Sum(x => x.Amount.ToDecimal(MoneyUnit.BTC));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use http://blockchainsql.io to SQL query the Bitcoin blockchain.

*Disclaimer*: I am the developer.

Comment: Just a note: when I click on GitHub/Twitter/Facebook or any contact link nothing happens.

Comment: @herman Can you provide a sample query to show how a getbalance equivalent query can be done on the sql database. For e.g in bitcoin cli console I run below set of commands to find balance of an address 1PWC7PNHL1SgvZaN7xEtygenKjWobWsCuf as below

`createwallet "wallet-1" true
loadwallet wallet-1
importaddress "1PWC7PNHL1SgvZaN7xEtygenKjWobWsCuf" "" false
getbalance`

Comment: @kdas

# All deposits to bitmex

[https://blockchainsql.io/rR1gE3](https://blockchainsql.io/rR1gE3)

# All deposits to bitmex of at least 1 btc

[https://blockchainsql.io/FkuyZ7](https://blockchainsql.io/FkuyZ7)